# PDO which is the correct syntax to specify named parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

To find users in a table, PDO prepared statements are used:

```
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase", "username", "password");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT surname, username FROM users
   WHERE (username=:u OR surname LIKE :sn);");
```

To specify the named parameters here :u and :sn, both the two ways give good results.

First, with colon preceeding the variable name **:u** and **:sn**:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
    ":u" => "johndoe2"
  , ":sn" => "%super%"
));
```

Or with the bare variable names **u** and **sn**:

```
$stmt->execute(array(
    "u" => "johndoe2"
  , "sn" => "%super%"
));
```

Which syntax is standard and preferred?

Comment: @downvoter, please explain your reason ?

Comment: Both are acceptable, depends on your coding preferences. Personally, I don't bother with the extra colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely use either because the binding mechanism will simply prefix your parameter name with a colon if one is not found.

See https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L363

```
if (is_param && param->name[0] != ':') {
    char *temp = emalloc(++param->namelen + 1);
    temp[0] = ':';
    memmove(temp+1, param->name, param->namelen);
    param->name = temp;
} else {
    param->name = estrndup(param->name, param->namelen);
}
```

I prefer to use the former as I feel like I'm saving a minuscule amount cycles.

Comment: Effectively, the colon is handled in the source C coded. We can use both.

Comment: @jacouh err, yeah. That's exactly what my answer says

Answer (score 3):

Looking up in the documentation for [bindParam](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php):

> **Parameter identifier**:
>
> For a prepared statement using named placeholders, this will be a
> parameter name of the form :name. For a prepared statement using
> question mark placeholders, this will be the 1-indexed position of the
> parameter.